# SwiftUI How to trigger a list row update

Tags: swift, mvvm

I'm using the following view model to feed a two sections list:

```
class ProjectModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var title: String = ""
    @Published var fragments: [Fragment] = []
    @Published var sources: [Source] = [] 
    
    func update(_ project: Project) {
        title = project.info.title  
        fragments = project.fragments
        sources = project.sources        
    }
}
```

Where `Fragment` and `Source` are `Identifiable` and `Hashable` structs. In the content view I have some controls that allow project editing. A simplified version of the view could be as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var projectModel: ProjectModel
   @State private var selection: Set<UUID> = [] 

   var body: some View {
       List($selection) {
          Section {
             ForEach(projectModel.sources) { source in 
                Button {
                   ...
                } label: {
                   SourceView(source: source)
                }
             }
          }

          Section {
             ForEach(projectModel.fragments) { fragment in 
                Button {
                   ...
                } label: {
                   FragmentView(fragment: fragment)
                }
             }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

[image: This is an example of the list]

Inserting or removing items operations trigger list update. Also when I replace an item, i.e. when I change the `id: UUID` property the list updates related rows. The problem occurs when I change a field of a `Fragment` or a `Source`. It seems that the model is not publishing the change. Or maybe, the list doesn't receive the change because the `id` properties remain the same (actually no changes are made to arrays). Maybe I'm missing something in logic? I'm studying/working with SwiftUI since a few moths.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Fragment` and `Source` are `Hashable`, changing one of their field also changes their `hashValue` property. In the `ForEach` statement we can use that property as `id`, so it can detect field changes:

```
@State private var selectionSet: Set<UUID> = []

List(selection: $selectionSet) {
    ForEach(projectModel.fragments, id: \.hashValue) { fragment in 
        FragmentView(id: fragment.id)
    }
}
```

This approach causes a logical issue in the `List` integrity. In fact, using some assistive technology, such as VoiceOver, moving VO focus onto the list it says: "No item selected" even if a `selectionSet` is not empty.

The final solution I adopted is to remove the `id: \.hashValue` and come back to the normal `id` identifiers and sending a special notification where a source or a fragment is updated:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let itemUpdated = Notification.Name("ItemUpdated")
}
```

In the view that modifying, say a fragment:

```
struct FragmentEdit: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ...
        Button("Update") {
            // Update the fragment than send
            // the .itemUpdated notification using fragmentId
            // as notification object.
        }
    }
}
```

While in the `FragmentView` View:

```
struct FragmentView: View {
    var fragmentId: UUID 

    @State private var title: String = "" 
    @State private var info1: String = "" 
    @State private var info2: String = "" 
    ...
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
            Text(info1)
            Text(info2
            ...
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .itemUpdated)) { obj in
            guard let id = obj.object as? UUID, id == fragmentId else { return }
            Task {
                await fillFragmentInfo()
            }
        }
    }

    private func fillFragmentInfo() {
        // Here you can update the state-variables using the 
        // id property to retrieve the fragment (that now is updated).
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best (or recommended) solution, but seems to be a good workaround.